# Parsing PowerShell response from Invoke-PsExec

Tags: powershell

I'm running a command using the `Invoke-PsExec` module which outputs the following result:

```
@{ComputerName=xxxxxx; Ping=False; ExitCode=; STDOUT=; STDERR=}
@{ComputerName=xxxxxx; Ping=True; ExitCode=1; STDOUT=; STDERR=}
...
```

I'm looking to parse the output and do something when the ExitCode is not 1. I tried parsing as a string, but this doesn't appear to work:

```
$x = Invoke-PsExec -Cn $computername -Command $cmd -HideSummary
if ($x -contains "ExitCode=1") {
    # do something
} else {
    # do something else
}
```

I'm presuming the result is an object, but how do you parse the elements?

Comment: Do you want to do something for each result where the exit code isn't 1? If any of the exit codes isn't 1? Do you want to do something different for results where the exit code is 1? Do you want to handle each result separately?

Comment: the answer below captures my requirement, but to answer your comment, im interested in if it's 1 or anything else, not individual responses.

Comment: I meant if you want to handle each object separately or all of them at once, not if you want to handle individual exit codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an array of objects, so you need to use a loop and then use dot notation to access the properties:

```
$x = Invoke-PsExec -Cn $computername -Command $cmd -HideSummary
foreach($c in $x) {
 if ($c.ExitCode -eq 1) { 
   # Do something ... 
 }
}
```